# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, coredump

I've been writing a C code which takes in an array of integers and adds 1 to every value in the array. However, I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void add1(int a[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++){
a[i]=a[i]+1;
    }
}


void main(){
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,76,7,5,3};
    add1(arr);
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++){
arr[i]=arr[i]+1;
printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}


}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` == `10 * sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(a)` == `sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can identify three issues in your program and would list them in progression of severity

1. (Code Error) Array size  is not the same as size of an array object

   ```
   for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++)
   ```

   Your assumption that the sizeof would return you the array size (no of elements) is wrong. [sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is used to calculate the size of the datatype, which in this case is an array of integers of size 10.

   You should instead have done

   ```
   for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);i++)
   ```

   which means, size of the array object as a reciprocal of sizeof a single array element.
2. (Functional Error) Array degenerates to a pointer when you pass it to a function.

   ```
   void add1(int a[]){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++){
   ```

   So, the `sizeof` would instead return the size of an integer pointer rather than the size of the array. You should instead pass the array size as an additional parameter

   ```
   void add1(int a[], size_t sz){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i < sz;i++){
   ```
3. (Style) Initialization of an array does not require an explicit array size

   ```
   int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,76,7,5,3};
   ```

   should be

   ```
   int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,76,7,5,3};
   ```

Comment: Or it could be a typo of `76,` for `7, 6,`. Or maybe he wants a 10 element array with `arr[9] == 0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: May be, but I cannot guess, if its a Typo. Regarding the second case, could be, but still for a singleton element, I would prefer to enumerate it.